# How to listen to Server Sent Events

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

I am building an Electron (1.8.4) app. How do I listen for SSE, the usual JavaScript  :

`var evtSource = new EventSource("https://www.someurl.com/sse");`

gives me the error :

> EventSource is not defined.

Are SSEs not supported in Electron? I could not find anything in the API reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by downloading eventsource.js from [this](https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource) JavaScript standalone implementation of the EventSource client. Then, in my main.js I added:

```
const EventSource = require(path.join(__dirname, 'eventsource.js'));
```

As an added note, native EventSource does work within script tags in the source (HTML) of a window, but not in the Javascript (Node.js) source for a windowless app.